# Google Spreadsheet Formatting Rules

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

I did some web-scraping and got data from a website on my Google Spreadsheet.
The Data looks like this:
1.2M,
3.5M,
324k,
989k,
1.01M

I want to format them into ONLY digits. (M = Million / k = thousand)
-> The finished table should look like this:
12000000
35000000
324000
...

Is there a way to tell Google Spreadsheet that "if last character ="M/k" ... do this ...
I can't come up with a good solution and I cant change the scraping results I get. I only recieve these numbers hardcoded as shown. (1.2M ... 342k...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, separate the number from the letter in an adjacent column:

```
=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)
```

Then use IF to check which letter and multiple the adjacent column by 1,000,000 or 1,000:

```
=IF(Right(A1)="M",B1*1000000,B1*1000)

A       B       C
1.2M    1.2     1200000
3.5M    3.5     3500000
324K    324     324000
989K    989     989000
1.01M   1.01    1010000
```